# JavaScript : How to extract complex content in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
var chartDataArrayString = '[0.00,0.00],[0.00,0.00],[0.00,0.00],[0.00,0.00],[0.00,0.00],[0.00,0.00],[0.00,0.00],[0.00,0.00],[0.00,0.00],[0.00,0.00],[8.44,10.55],[51.79,64.74]';
```

Now I want to extract each unit from this string and put it in a 2 dimension array.
So there will be 12 elements in the 2D array and each element has 2 values.
So it should look like this

```
var 2dArray = [[470, 870.45], [560, 920.49], [350, 540.12], [600, 901.59], [500, 750.4], [620, 401], [480, 724.4], [530, 598.98], [630, 630], [400, 876.69], [220, 1100.2], [500, 1021.9]];
```

I tried to use ',' to split it, but I found inside each small unit, there is a ',' as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one line with `JSON.parse()` as shown in am not i am's answer.

But since you were talking about using `.split()` here's one way to make that work:

```
var dataArray = chartDataArrayString.slice(1,-1).split("],[");

for (var i=0; i < dataArray.length; i++)
    dataArray[i] = dataArray[i].split(",");
```

That is, use `.slice()` to remove the initial `[` and trailing `]` and then split on `"],["` creating an array of strings in the form `"0.00,0.00"`. Then iterate through each item in the array to create the nested arrays with another split.

EDIT: For the inner elements to be numbers rather than strings you can do something like the following (which just makes it even more obvious that JSON.parse() is the "correct" solution):

```
for (var i=0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
    dataArray[i] = dataArray[i].split(",").map(Number);
}
```

Comment: You'll just need the *toNumber* conversion to get a number result instead of numeric strings.

Comment: ...take the ES5 train... `dataArray[i].split(",").map(Number)`

Comment: Good point @amnotiam - Looking at the source data with trailing zeros I was thinking strings. Answer updated with your suggestion.

Comment: @nnnnnn, Thanks to your solution, could you please explain the method map()? I cannot find it. thanks And why did you say the JSON.parse() is correct?

Comment: The Array [`.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new array where each element will be the result of calling a function you provide (in this case `Number()`) for every element in the original array. Note that it's not supported in IE until version 9, though the MDN page I linked to gives a workaround. I said `JSON.parse()` is "correct" (in quotes) because I think it is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `JSON.parse`, and concatenate in the outer Array...

```
var data = JSON.parse("[" + chartDataArrayString + "]");
```

You could also use `.eval()`, but `JSON.parse` is a little nicer/safer as long as the data is compliant.

Comment: hi I'm new to JavaScript, so I don't know how to concatenate them . Although I took nnnnn's way to do it, but I am more  interested in your way. I would be grateful if you could show how you do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Franva: My code example shows the concatenation of the `"["` and `"]"`. It's just the *array literal* syntax that is being added to the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`:

```
var arr = eval('[' + data + ']');
```

or you can play with the string:

```
var arr = [];
var bits = data.replace(/(^\[)|(\]$)/g,'').split('],[');

for (var i=0, iLen=bits.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  arr[i] = bits[i].split(',');
}
```

whatever suits. Oh, and note that the values will be strings, not numbers.